# Stem para Twitter

Tags: r, twitter-api

Caros colegas, 
Estou tentando fazer uma análise de twitters de uma timeline e precisava stemiatizar os textos para análise. Estou tentando o seguinte procedimento:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
tweets <- userTimeline("Pragmatismo_", n = 3000)
tweets.df <- twListToDF(tweets)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets.df$text))
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*", "", x) 
removeNumPunct <- function(x) gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', x)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(removeNumPunct))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(removeURL))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, ptstem)
```

A questão é que mesmo após o último comando `myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, ptstem)` o texto não aparece stemizado.

Alguma dica?
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Será que isso te ajuda? https://github.com/dfalbel/ptstem

Comment: Vou tentar. Obrigado!

Comment: A função `ptstem` que é utilizada em `tm_map` a princípio nao está definida na questão, e nem nas bibliotecas mais comuns para esse fim. Voce poderia indicar de qual pacote você retirou a mesma? Ou insira a função que tu programou...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A principal função de *stemming* empregada na `tm_map` é a [stemDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197636/how-is-the-correct-use-of-stemdocument), mas como é apresentado na resposta dessa pergunta, não é possível utilizar a mesma para o português devido a um `bug`.

O que eu fiz para contornar a situaçao foi utilizar o pacote `quanteda`:

```
library(quanteda)
my_dfm <- dfm_wordstem(myCorpus, language = "pt")
```

Outra opção, seria adaptar se possível o uso da função `ptstem::ptstem_words` no seu contexto (não testei).